# AJAX form submit with file upload

Tags: php, ajax, forms

I am trying to ajax submit a form that contains file upload area. As I found out JS cannot handle file uploads therefore I am using this plugin -> http://jquery.malsup.com/form/#ajaxForm

However, after submitting the form, I am not getting anything in `$_FILES`.  Does anyone know what is the reason and how I can fix this?

My input field is `<input type="file" name="logo" id="logo" />` and yes the form is multipart data.

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at http://www.ajaxf1.com/tutorial/ajax-file-upload-tutorial.html

Answer (score 1):

use this plugin it uses XHR for uploading multiple files with progress-bar in FF3.6+, Safari4+, Chrome and falls back to hidden iframe based upload in other browsers, providing good user experience everywhere. check this: http://valums.com/ajax-upload/