# uploading file using ajax submit

Tags: java, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to upload a file and get the contents in java controller and write it to my specified path.It works when I submit the form as usual but now I want to upload file using ajax submit.I don't know ajax and tried googling but in vain.Please anyone suggest some tutorial or guide me how to do it.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

there is no direct way to upload using ajax but one way to simulate using iframe

Please have a look on these discussion

[How can I upload files asynchronously?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/166221/how-can-i-upload-files-asynchronously-with-jquery)
[AJAX form submit with file upload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5561127/ajax-form-submit-with-file-upload)

Ajax Style File Uploading using Hidden iFrame

http://viralpatel.net/blogs/ajax-style-file-uploading-using-hidden-iframe/

Answer (score 0):

try this plug in

```
<script>
    // wait for the DOM to be loaded
    $(document).ready(function() 
    {
        // bind 'myForm' and provide a simple callback function
       $("#tempForm").ajaxForm({
       url:'../calling action or servlet',
       type:'post',
       beforeSend:function()
       {
         alert("perform action before making the ajax call like showing spinner image");
       },
       success:function(e){
        alert("data is"+e);
            alert("now do whatever you want with the data");
       }
       });
    });
</script>
```

and keep this inside your form

```
<form id="tempForm" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="file" name="" id="" />
</form>
```

and you can find the plug in [here](http://www.malsup.com/jquery/form/#download)

if you have mentioned the ecntype in your form then it would pass the filles as byte field , there you have to use

```
String photo = request.getParameter('inputFile').getBytes();
```

this byte can be stored as a.blob in sql

Comment: but how to get the value of file field in controller,I mean contents of the uploaded file.If I do request.getParameter("xsl") for var xsl=$("#fileId").val() I will get only file name.